# What is the foundational book of Czerny finger exercises for piano?

Tags: technique, piano, practice, exercises, sheet-music

I've recently started teaching myself piano (via Bartok's Mikrokosmos) and feel it would be helpful to supplement the pieces with some standard exercises. Everyone I speak with suggests Czerny, but there are simply a ton of different books of his collected exercises; I'm not sure where the best place is to start. Is there one Czerny book that stands out as being particularly foundational?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Czerny Op. 599, Études, (Erster Wiener Lehrmeister im Pianofortespiel ) is usually the volume to start.

Comment: Thanks! I ended up asking a super-piano-friend who suggested the exact same volume! I appreciate the help!

Answer (score 3):

I'd suggest not doing Czerny. A lot of people don't realize that the Czerny studies were written *specifically* as preparatory exercises for the Beethoven Sonatas. If you don't know which studies match up to which sonatas, you're not doing anyone any favors. Learn to play scales and common chord progressions. From there, I'd progress to Liszt, Dohnanyi, or Brahms technical studies. My preference is Liszt.

Comment: Thanks, Josh! Are there certain scales to learn, specifically, or is every scale book going to have the same fingerings in them?

Comment: Pretty much all scales will have the same fingerings. Peter Feuchtwangler, who I admire very much, worked out some alternate fingerings, if you can track those down. They're very nice.

Comment: I disagree that Czerny is solely for Beethoven. I only know Czerny's Op. 740 (and some etudes of op. 365). But I think this is a great book to learn a lot of technical challenges which help for various advanced works from various composers particularly also for the Chopin etudes. For example there is a study on double thirds. Afterall Czerny taught Franz Liszt, the greatest pianist of all time.

Comment: Part 2: The only thing which if I remember correctly Op.740 and Op. 365 is lacking of when compared to for example the Brahms studies are polyrhythms. I remember that in the Brahms studies there are many polyrhythms. But if you can play Op. 740 and Op. 365, I don't think you will have anymore problems with most polyrhythms...

Answer (score 2):

I personally prefer Hanon but Czerny's 101 Exercises are great

Comment: Thanks, Alex! I ended up choosing Eugen's answer due to the fact that I was looking for the industry-standard. I'll for sure take a look at the Hanon, though.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what kind of music you want to play.  Czerny builds technique suitable for the classical era.  Hanon build more general finger strength and agility and is often suggested for beginners.  Oscar Peterson Etudes are great if you want to get into jazz.

Comment: Take a look at Czerny Op. 740 or Op. 365. It don't t see why these etudes are specifically for the classical era. They are etudes to play the romantic repertoire.

Answer (score 1):

I use Czerny's "School of Velocity" Op. 299.
I would definetly recommend that book, it is great for building finger strength, speed, and accuracy.
They may be a bit hard for a beginner though.